# How can I find out how many days my website had been online?

Tags: website, web-hosting

I'm a website designer . Due to some problems, I need to know find out how many days my website had been online on web hosting? Is there any way to find this question?

Comment: This may help, enter your url.  https://archive.org/web/

Comment: If your server is popular enough your server logs might give you some clues ...

Comment: do you mean my host manager can help me?

Comment: log on to your server and look at the server logs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `@DavidPostill`. I'm using `Parallels Plesk Panle`.
1. Login into your account.
2. Go to `Website & Domain`. 
3. Expand `Show Advanced Operations`.
4. Then click On `Log`.
5. Here you can see all transactions with date and time such as first time you uploaded some files and etc...

I hope, this could be a little help from me to you.

[image]